# Can't build anymore on Cordova after activating iOS app group and service notification extension

Tags: cordova, onesignal, ios-app-group, cordova-ios, unnotificationserviceextension

I have an mobile application under :
- Cordova 8.1.2.
- iOS platform 5.0.0
- onesignal-cordova-plugin 2.4.7
- Xcode 10.2.1

Everything was ok. Building &co.

Then I tried to activate the iOS Service notification extension in order to have Media Attachments.

I followed these docs from OneSignal (in this order) :
- https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-sdk-setup#section-1-add-notification-service-extension-recommend-
- https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-sdk-app-groups-setup

Everything was ok. I was able to launch the app from Xcode and the Media attachments tests were OK.

But then I try to build again my app in CLI and I have the issue :
CordovaError: Could not find *-Info.plist file, or config.xml file.

I think Xcode changed some parameter but I can't figure what...

If you have any idea, it will be really appreciated.

Thx in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

it`s my case too)

Just open a worksplace instead xcodeproject when you work in xCode